# how to solve the "Trying to get property 'post_content' of non-object" in the wordpress debug file (Jumping anchor issue)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a menu in my WP website (Botiga theme) made of links to anchors to the homepage .
The problem is that the scroll isn't smooth when I click to a link menu (there's like a jumping effect in the scrolling)

I activated the debug mode and I have this in my debug file : "PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'post_content' of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\wp-goyohan-shop\wp-content\plugins\athemes-blocks\classes\class-athemes-blocks-init.php on line 121"

Here is the line 121 of this file

```
116    if( is_admin() || is_customize_preview() ) {
117                wp_enqueue_script( 'athemes-blocks-parallax' );
118            } else {
119                global $post;
120
121                if( strpos( $post->post_content, 'parallax' ) !== FALSE ) {
122                    wp_enqueue_script( 'athemes-blocks-parallax' );
123                } else {
124                    $block_widgets = get_option( 'widget_block' );
125                    if( $block_widgets ) {
126                        foreach( $block_widgets as $block_widget ) {
127                            if( isset($block_widget['content']) && strpos( $block_widget['content'], 'wp:athemes/' ) !== FALSE && strpos( $block_widget['content'], 'parallax' ) !== FALSE ) {
128                                wp_enqueue_script( 'athemes-blocks-parallax' );
129                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I guess the problem comes from the line 121 that is always FALSE
I made a var_dump($post) that returns NULL and...that's my limit.

Any suggestions to clean this bug?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: Also, why not check whether `$post === null` before accessing it?

Comment: The thing is that $post is NULL but i don't why... And if the bug comes from the fact that this variable is null, i don't what to do to change that.